# Поиск моделей по условию через many_to_many

Tags: django, django-orm

Есть такая модель.
Нужно написать запрос который бы нашёл модели у которых нет `required_models`. То есть те у которых запрос `my_model.required_models.all()` вернул бы пустой `query_set`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default="", blank=True)
    required_models = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self", related_name="released_models", blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

Если бы была прописана промежуточная модель, то это было бы легче.

```
class ThroughModel(models.Model):
    required_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, null=True)
    released_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, null=True)
```

Тогда запросом былобы что-то вроде:

```
TroughModel.objects.filter(required_model=None)
```

А потом из них уже получить нужные `MyModel`

Помогите через many_to_many составить. Сам что-то не могу сообразить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать Field lookup `isnull`

```
MyModel.objects.filter(required_models__isnull=True)
```

[Здесь можно прочитать про Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)

Comment: Хм. Там пример с __isnull был для обычного поля, не для менеджера связанных моделей. Но так действительно можно. Спасибо.